# sorting integers and percentage values both in single column using jquery table sorter

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I am facing issue with table sorter i have a column with both integers and percentage values so after applying the sorting the column is getting sorted by considering integer values.

For Example,If i have the values like 4.19, which is more than 4.48%, but  4.48% is first even though the percentage (4.48%) is less than 4.19.

Can anyone help me out this.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Can you please share an example. I'll even make it easy... update [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3877/).

Comment: Yes i updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3880/)  please verify it i gave 4.48% and 4.19 value so the descending order is not correct

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it that you are expecting to happen? And how is 4.19 > 4.48%; do you mean 4.48% = 0.0448?

Comment: Yes i want the percentage value should get calculated as decimal(0.0448) and then it must sort

Comment: Mottie,Here you mentioned "calc-percent" id where should i add it to the table column.can you please explain clear

Comment: I integrated the code you had given but not applied please give some clear explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a percentage into a fraction, you'll need to add a custom parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3883/)):

```
$(function () {

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "calc-percent",
        is: function(s) {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table) {
            var v =  s ? $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/%/g, ""), table)/100 : s;
            return /%/.test(s) ? v/100 : v;
        },
        type: "numeric"
    });

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headers: {
            1: { sorter: "calc-percent" }
        },
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
});
```